# Div Background Width browser

Tags: css, background

I want the header background and the footer background  as wide as the browser window.

On the top i think it´s ok but the footer background isn´t it

on [PSR](http://psr.mediameans.de)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the `header` div, keep the `footer` div outside `wrapper`. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Set width to `100%`:

```css
#footer { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: @tom_means replace your `width: inherit` with `width: 100%`.